# Is there a way in Excel to edit a selected row in another sheet?

Tags: excel, events, vba

I am struggling, wondering if there is any simple way to reference a cell from the current/active row.

i.e. - I have 2 sheets, one with lots of info on and the second I want to display info from the current/active row on Sheet 1.

So say row 5 was selected in Sheet 1. Then if you went to Sheet 2, all the info from row 5 would show on Sheet 2. Then if you selected row 8 on Sheet 1, the info on Sheet 2 would be updated to show only the info from row 8 on Sheet 1.

Any changes that you made on Sheet 2 would be reflected when you went back to Sheet 1.

Is there maybe a simple formula I could add to the cells on Sheet 2? Maybe something along the lines of:

```
cell A1 on sheet 2 have =sheet1(active_row.colum1) 

and then cell A2 on sheet 2 have =sheet1(active_row.colum2)
```

etc, etc

I've managed to get it kind of working using a macro, but the only trouble is that when I alter the info on Sheet 2, it doesn't update the info on Sheet 1. If there was a way to add this functionality to my code, that would be great.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myList
If Target.Address <> Target.EntireRow.Address Then Exit Sub
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
myList = [{"B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10","B11","B12","B13","B14","B15"}] '<- adjust to your need
With Target.EntireRow
    For i = 1 To UBound(myList)
        Sheets("sheet2").Range(myList(i)).Value = .Cells(i).Value
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: It could be done with VBA. But are you sure the selection in anohter sheet is the right thing to do to highlight a Range? It would be far simpler to write 5, or 8 in a cell in the second or in another sheet. Then all the changing on the second sheet could be driven by formulas.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean? But if there is a simpler way of doing things then I'm definitely up for it! :)

Comment: All I want to be able to do is say I'm on row 5 on sheet 1, I want sheet 2 to show all the info from sheet1, row5. Then if I move to say row 12 on sheet1, I want the info on sheet2 to change from showing info from sheet1,row5 to showing info from sheet1,row12. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this very well :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but **it's a little bit complicated**.

You want the row selected on Sheet 1 to display on Sheet 2, and then have be able to edit Sheet 2 to automatically update Sheet 1.

What you have to do is use the Selection event as you are, and copy the row to Sheet 2.  Then you have to use the Activate event on Sheet 1 to copy the row back to Sheet 1.  Please note that the following code assumes that Sheet 1 has no worksheet functions (formulas) in the cells, you could still do it, but you'd have to preserve the formulas and replace them.

**Sheet 1 Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address <> Target.EntireRow.Address Then Exit Sub
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Target.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Target.Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

**Sheet 2 Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") > 0 Then
  Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).Copy
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Rows(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")).EntireRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No, Excel does not work this way:

You cannot do this with a formula. There are no Functions that work with the active cell on the active sheet or another sheet. Also the Excel calculation engine does not recognise the need to recalculate when you change selection or move between sheets.

Comment: I thought this might be the case really. I've kind of managed to do it within a macro, but the only trouble is that if I alter the info on sheet2, it doesn't updatet the info on sheet1. If anyone has any tips on how I could perhaps add this functionality, that would be great. I've updated my question to show the macro code I have so far :)

Comment: If you assign the macro to a keystroke then you can rerun it easily. It's not as automatic as you'd like, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Not sure how I'd go about that really. Would this mean that if I altered something on sheet two, it would update the info on sheet1? Any help with this would be great! as I've pretty much got it doing what I want, it's just adding the functionality of being able to edit the info displayed by the macro and having this update on the master sheet would be brilliant! I've updated my question at the top to show the macro code I have so far :)